# Calling "me/groups" using Python Facebook SDK returns empty data

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, get, facebook-group

I want information from groups where I am and I can not get it. Always the code returns an empty data.

```
{u'data': []}
```

My code is as follows:

```
import facebook

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token='my token')
a = graph.get_object('me/groups')
print(a)
```

What is wrong? I'm using Python 2.7.10 and Facebook official sdk.
I've tried with `facepy` and it's the same, empty data.

Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

First you question isn't complete. You need to show what permissions you are asking for and what API version you are using. That said I suspect one of two things.

You are not using the necessary permission "user_managed_groups".

Or

You don't realize that with that permission that "groups" edge will only return the groups which the user is an admin of.

It is not possible to do anything with a group that the logged in user is not an admin of via the API.  Learn about me/groups [HERE](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups/)

Comment: thanks for your answer. And how i can do that? i can post in a few groups if i put the id manually, but i want to automate...

Comment: Automate by spamming all your groups?

Comment: no, i want to publish a service in a few groups, and automate that. But i don't know how to get the list of my groups

Comment: There is no way to get your groups via the API. FB removed this feature due to spam.